# Opening xls files using xlrd without pathname

Tags: python, python-2.7, xls, xlrd

Usually the xlrd library uses pathname/filename to read the file  as follows

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('some_filename.xls')
```

But in my flask project i am dealing with an uploaded file.So i got the file as

```
xlsfile = request.files['file']
```

So how can i use this file object in xlrd.?

Comment: `xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfile.filename)` - is this what you are after?

Comment: iirc, `open_workbook` can take a `file_contents` argument.

Comment: @marcin Actually that won't work either. >>>>>No such file or directory: u'test.xlsx'

Comment: I think you need to provide full path: `xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], xlsfile.filename))`. Can you check this?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks. Although file_contents arguement worked perfectly.

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = xlsfile.read())
Thanks for your quick response

Comment: @Marcin oh I never realized that Flask saves uploaded files to disk. Interesting